Containerize a .Net Webassembly Standalone app
I have created 3 projects in the same solution using .Net 8 under the traditional "Core Hosted" structure.
Solution
Client
Server
Shared
Will I be able to containerize these projects all together in docker or will I have to create individual projects and containerize them separately?
Thanks!

Hi @Darkmatter5, You can containerize multiple projects together in a single Docker container, but it's generally recommended to containerize them separately. It provides better scalability, isolation, and manageability.
